# espeak skips the first phoneme of the sentence

Tags: espeak, mbrola

I am trying to use espeak for text to speech on a respeaker core v2.
If my sentence is "Begin Recording", then espeak only speaks "egin Recording". It occasionally says it correctly. How do I fix this?

I tried adding some random characters ahead of the text like "_", "," etc. But the problem persists

I am using this command `espeak -ven-en+m2 -s140 "Begin Recording"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an easy workaround.
I noticed that the problem occurs only for the first time I use this command.
Worked around by adding a dummy espeak command for blank text.

`espeak -ven-en+m2 -s140 ""` followed by
`espeak -ven-en+m2 -s140 "Begin Recording"`